# How to convert MySQL query to Morris chart readable json

Tags: php, mysql, json, charts, morris.js

I have a MySQL query that exports json data after some php intervention.

The json data is needed to activate a morris.js charts.

This is the code I have now:

```
$lp = array('35', '95', '96');

print '<script>$(document).ready(function() { var day_data = ';
foreach ($lp as $value) {
    $data_array = array();
    foreach ($this->dbh->query("
        SELECT c.datefield AS DATE, IFNULL(COUNT(l.insertDate),0) AS TASK
        FROM calendar c
        LEFT JOIN lead l ON ( DATE( l.insertDate ) = c.datefield )
            AND l.lpid =  '$value'
        GROUP BY DATE
        ORDER BY c.datefield DESC
        LIMIT 30
    ") as $row) {
         //$data_array .=  $row['TASK'];   
         //echo '{"date": "'.$row['DATE'].'", "page 1": '.$row['TASK'].', "page 2": 5},';

         array_push($data_array, $row['DATE'], $row['TASK']);
         //$data_array = array_merge($data_array, array('date' => $row['DATE'],'val' => $row['TASK']));
    }
    echo json_encode($data_array);      
}
```

What I want is to be able to see in the chart dynamic data for more than one id. this is the json I want to achieve:

```
{"date": "01-01-2017", "page 35": 3, "page 95": 5, "page 96": 5},
{"date": "02-01-2017", "page 35": 4, "page 95": 3, "page 96": 3},
{"date": "02-01-2017", "page 35": 9, "page 95": 5, "page 96": 4},
{"date": "03-01-2017", "page 35": 0, "page 95": 8, "page 96": 5};
```

Maybe a better suggestion is to export the json data by id and then combine it by date in the frontend.

Comment: Note that RIGHT JOINs are fantastically rare. Just saying.

Comment: any suggestions to use instead of right join?

Comment: I'll edit your code...

Comment: O.K The left join works as well. do you have any suggestion how can i manipulate the query in order to get the json format i wrote above?

Comment: What needs to be done now?  I am confused.  Did Strawberry perfect your query?  Have you displayed in your question, the correct formatted json format that needs to be generated?  You want the id value included right? Or just have separate rows for ids included?

Comment: Where do the values come from for the 3 nominated pages?

Comment: @mickmackusa, strawberry indeed perffected the query and I thank him for that. but the query output is stil the same. The data for the qury comes ffrom two spesific tables as displayd in the link, Yes, I want the id included. All i want is json formated data that will show a chart as in this example. http://jsbin.com/uzosiq/258/embed?js,output. if you could help me I will be more than greatfull. maybe a better solution will be to export all the data to a json file and than call it using an ajax function. the issue is that thius is a complicates sql query and I dont know that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my full working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Morris.js Bar Chart For DavSev</title>   
</head>
<body>
<?php
$pdo=new PDO("mysql:host=host;dbname=DB;charset=utf8","username","password");
$params=array(35,95,96);  // lps list
$js_cols="'".implode("','",$params)."'";
$placeholders=array_fill(0,sizeof($params),'?');
$sql="SELECT C.datefield AS `date`,L.lpid AS `lp`,IFNULL(COUNT(L.insertDate),0) AS `task` 
      FROM `calendar` C 
      LEFT JOIN `lead` L ON DATE(L.insertDate)=C.datefield
      WHERE L.lpid IN (".implode(',',$placeholders).")
      GROUP BY `DATE`,L.lpid
      ORDER BY C.datefield,L.lpid;";
$stmt=$pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if(!isset($data[$row["date"]])){
        $data[$row["date"]]=array_replace(array("D"=>$row["date"]),array_fill_keys($params,0));
    }
    $data[$row["date"]][$row["lp"]]=$row["task"];
}           
?>
<div id="bar-example"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
Morris.Bar({
    element: 'bar-example',
    data: <?=json_encode(array_values($data))?>,  // shorthand echo
    xkey: 'D',
    ykeys: [<?=$js_cols?>],  // shorthand echo
    labels: [<?=$js_cols?>]  // shorthand echo
});
</script>
</html>
```

- I changed your external script links.
- I used pdo and a parameterized statement in case the `lps` are user input.
- I changed your query to suit my needs. Please review and compare so that you understand the query changes.
- I temporarily use `date` as keys to properly build the `$data` array.
- I default all `lp`'s values-per-date to zero, then overwrite it (last line of while loop) if the `lp` has a value on the date.
- I use `array_values()` before `json_encode()` to strip the `date`-keys from the array.

Rendered Output:

[image]

Source code Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Morris.js Bar Chart Example</title>  
</head>
<body>
<div id="bar-example"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
Morris.Bar({
    element: 'bar-example',
    data: [{"D":"2017-04-09","35":0,"95":0,"96":"1"},{"D":"2017-04-10","35":0,"95":0,"96":"1"},{"D":"2017-04-11","35":"1","95":"4","96":"1"},{"D":"2017-04-12","35":0,"95":0,"96":"1"},{"D":"2017-04-15","35":"2","95":0,"96":"1"},{"D":"2017-04-16","35":0,"95":0,"96":"1"}],
    xkey: 'D',
    ykeys: ['35','95','96'],
    labels: ['35','95','96']
});
</script>
</html>
```

I think I may still have the `labels` portion of the `Morris.Bar` function wrong, but I'll let you play with that if you wish.  I've put in a fair amount of time on this.

Comment: Thank you very much, I aknowladge your effort. as you were able to see i voted up your former answer.  I will check the answer you have posted above. can you please give me an export of the database you have used. something is not working for me and i would like to trace your actions?

Comment: Forget it, dont need the database.

Comment: @DavSev I guess you found the trailing comma in the export code that you provided.  Happy to help.  Best of luck with your project.